# Angular 7: index.aspx instead of index.html in ng build

Tags: sharepoint, angular7

I want to use my Angular 7 project for Sharepoint 2013. Some of my codes doesn't work in .html. That is why I want the index.html generated in dist folder to be index.aspx

In angular 5. I used to use ng eject and changed some setting that will set index to index.aspx instead of index.html when i build. But since ng eject no longer works in Angular 7 I am having problem on how to generate index.aspx when I build my project.

Expected result when I build a project should generate index.aspx instead of index.html

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite angular webpack config with the help of https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/custom-webpack
it includes guides and examples of how to use it. Hope it helps